# Loss doesn't converge for a siamese network aiming to compare objects

Tags: python, pytorch, neural-network, regression, loss

I want to develop a good siamese network model that compares two objects each one in a different image and return a value between 0 to 100 representing the percentage of that resemblance.
I want to precise that everything in the following code is tested and works just fine (converting images to tensors and loading into the dataloader, converting each tensor back into an image to compare them during the train function, the target tensor is also well produced as shown at the end)
even the network architecture looks pretty good even though it's far from optimal.

I've created a Siamese Network that aims to return a similarity percentage (0 to 100 %) with the following architecture:

```
Class SiameseNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SiameseNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=3)
        self.pool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(64,128, kernel_size=3)
        self.pool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=3)
        self.pool3 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2)
        self.conv4 = nn.Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=3)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(36864, 4096)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(4096, 1)
    def forward_once(self, x):
        x = self.pool1(torch.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool2(torch.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = self.pool3(torch.relu(self.conv3(x)))
        x = torch.relu(self.conv4(x))
        x = x.view(x.size()[0], -1)
        x = torch.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x) 
        return x

    def forward(self, image1, image2):
        output1 = self.forward_once(image1)
        output2 = self.forward_once(image2)
        size= output1.size(0)
        similarity_score= torch.empty(size)
        for z in range(size):
            similarity_score[z] =100 * expit((abs(output1[z].item() - output2[z].item())))
        return similarity_score
```

i calculated the percentage and returned it as the output of the network (expit is like a sigmoid function to make the result in range of (0 to 1))
(i also initiated it as a tensor so that it can contain all the training image tensors as well)

```
class ImageDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, root_dir):
        self.root_dir = root_dir
        self.image_paths = os.listdir(self.root_dir)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        img_path1 = os.path.join(self.root_dir, self.image_paths[index])
        img_path2 = os.path.join(self.root_dir, np.random.choice(self.image_paths))
        image1 = cv2.imread(img_path1)
        image2 = cv2.imread(img_path2)
        
        # Resize and center-crop images
        image1 = cv2.resize(image1, (130,130), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
        image2 = cv2.resize(image2, (130,130), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

        image1 = cv2.cvtColor(image1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        image2 = cv2.cvtColor(image2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

        image1= torch.from_numpy(image1).permute(2, 0, 1)
        image2= torch.from_numpy(image2).permute(2, 0, 1)

        return image1, image2

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.image_paths)
```

Here is the Dataset used it mostly resizes images to (130,130) and converts them to RGB as well as transforms them to tensors for the Dataloader .

```
def train_siamese_network(siamese_net, train_loader, criterion, optimizer, epochs):
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        running_loss = 0.0
        for i, (image1, image2) in enumerate(train_loader):
            size= image1.size(0)
            target = torch.empty(size)
            for j in range(size):
                image1index=image1[j]
                image2index=image2[j]
                image1indeximage = cv2.cvtColor(image1index.permute(1, 2, 0).numpy(), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
                image2indeximage = cv2.cvtColor(image2index.permute(1, 2, 0).numpy(), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
                target[j] = compare(image1indeximage, image2indeximage)
            
            
            image1 = image1.float()
            image2 = image2.float()
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            similarity_score = siamese_net(image1, image2)
            similarity_score.requires_grad = True   
            target.requires_grad = True
            
            loss = criterion(similarity_score, target)
            
                
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            running_loss += loss.item()

            if (i + 1) % 9 == 0:
                print(f"Epoch: {epoch+1}, Batch: {i+1}/{len(train_loader)}, Loss: {running_loss/9:.4f}")
                print(target)
                print(similarity_score)
                running_loss = 0.0
```

in the training, i extract the images from the tensors pairs and compare them using the compare function that uses opencv to return a value between 0 to 100 showing how much the objects inside are alike.

```
root_dir = "training images path with 808 images"
batch_size = 30
learning_rate = 0.001
epochs = 15
siamese_net = SiameseNetwork()

class MAELoss(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MAELoss, self).__init__()

    def forward(self, similarity_score, target):
        loss = F.l1_loss(similarity_score, target)
        return loss

criterion = MAELoss()

optimizer = optim.SGD(siamese_net.parameters(), lr=learning_rate, momentum=0.9)

train_dataset = ImageDataset(root_dir)
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
train_siamese_network(siamese_net, train_loader, criterion, optimizer, epochs)
```

In here i declared all the variables needed along with the loss function and optimizer i also took the training images from the root directory (there are 808 images)

The problem is that after running the code, the loss stays at around 15 to 20. and it never goes down from that. It seems like the network doesn't learn anything despite the fact that I used numerous regression loss functions (MSELoss, HuberLoss and MAELoss) and various optimizers (SGD, RMSProp and Adam) and changed many times the learning rate. The loss just doesn't move from that range.

Here's an example of a training output where after each expression : "Epoch: ....."
the first tensor is the target one
and the second is the similarity_score tensor (network output)

```
Epoch: 1, Batch: 9/27, Loss: 16.8451
tensor([43.6709, 59.7812, 73.7055, 59.6418, 83.5022, 49.1689, 90.7965, 81.1983,
        59.9834, 81.4762, 71.9924, 47.7223, 80.3145, 72.9440, 56.4668, 68.0254,
        81.3314, 62.0227, 62.7591, 87.1804, 77.3594, 56.1987, 55.9273, 48.9685,
        67.5465, 77.3194, 62.1281, 54.2897, 61.6744, 68.6310],
       requires_grad=True)
tensor([65.2761, 71.3080, 63.9012, 70.6474, 59.0761, 56.5358, 55.1871, 89.6672,
        65.0699, 79.0264, 56.8448, 94.8586, 70.9622, 94.8008, 79.1134, 86.9188,
        63.1806, 70.2783, 57.8123, 69.3419, 59.0280, 50.6458, 87.6556, 53.7716,
        86.8887, 60.2880, 62.4835, 70.9319, 86.6291, 60.4864],
       requires_grad=True)
Epoch: 1, Batch: 18/27, Loss: 17.1542
tensor([43.4745, 57.5868, 53.0728, 63.2955, 70.3727, 73.3549, 42.0392, 68.3287,
        48.1687, 52.2626, 67.1332, 50.2200, 58.9248, 49.6973, 55.4335, 84.9138,
        56.2597, 61.2831, 66.5006, 92.7535, 66.7124, 62.4881, 76.2798, 44.3287,
        75.1725, 62.3587, 51.2634, 65.9343, 67.8714, 88.2628],
       requires_grad=True)
tensor([80.2047, 61.4582, 61.2337, 89.3898, 62.0641, 88.0415, 84.2602, 59.3769,
        94.7057, 56.6337, 63.2712, 73.8873, 52.4539, 67.5783, 78.0391, 54.3334,
        59.6626, 53.2234, 76.9786, 59.4119, 89.7190, 80.2141, 82.2252, 51.5405,
        92.6856, 57.9521, 57.7640, 53.3699, 50.5302, 57.2413],
       requires_grad=True)
Epoch: 1, Batch: 27/27, Loss: 17.8211
tensor([65.3095, 58.5260, 73.4789, 51.3675, 61.7649, 39.4923, 66.2919, 44.4984,
        50.1306, 51.3093, 59.0769, 55.8848, 83.9803, 49.0435, 58.6354, 54.1619,
        59.4587, 48.4563, 79.9191, 60.1650, 71.9631, 95.1770, 64.1891, 56.4286,
        58.7675, 48.6227, 66.3928, 59.9121], requires_grad=True)
tensor([82.5282, 64.5972, 79.9229, 76.4612, 64.5173, 62.9886, 83.5669, 50.3927,
        58.7686, 81.6082, 50.5454, 75.5683, 51.1592, 61.9061, 88.4537, 51.5271,
        82.9370, 51.1047, 68.6368, 63.2251, 72.0028, 55.5717, 52.5471, 81.4833,
        86.8226, 52.8803, 76.0848, 96.9169], requires_grad=True)
Epoch: 2, Batch: 9/27, Loss: 17.5547
tensor([51.7690, 54.9610, 64.4040, 76.6931, 50.8097, 66.8009, 47.2387, 57.4117,
        84.3007, 58.9115, 78.2184, 52.7186, 66.1959, 54.2037, 62.7252, 41.7889,
        49.3951, 64.0432, 58.6790, 84.7277, 48.4168, 88.6789, 61.8902, 56.4878,
        67.7225, 70.7402, 50.9815, 59.5142, 51.7015, 52.3341],
       requires_grad=True)
tensor([79.1223, 83.1053, 61.9624, 76.0128, 65.0555, 50.3304, 52.1161, 54.3096,
        68.3509, 79.9759, 69.8160, 86.5434, 68.0318, 58.8131, 70.4833, 59.0492,
        90.2961, 66.0177, 82.2647, 79.7309, 75.3466, 63.3744, 76.4131, 89.4558,
        61.2280, 88.3747, 87.2557, 89.7001, 63.5280, 71.8147],
       requires_grad=True)
Epoch: 2, Batch: 18/27, Loss: 17.1488
tensor([59.8553, 52.9791, 63.9162, 69.9478, 48.7731, 57.6949, 63.7758, 44.5036,
        45.9982, 63.3561, 55.9080, 79.7382, 56.8107, 56.2182, 59.7970, 88.2774,
        58.4926, 69.4093, 74.8757, 69.8084, 77.0201, 52.4785, 50.6574, 89.3533,
        74.5024, 42.7168, 55.3500, 71.7523, 91.5000, 52.4813],
       requires_grad=True)
tensor([79.7290, 65.2994, 69.8504, 60.5113, 61.1297, 89.2263, 72.4197, 66.8873,
        86.2056, 75.6067, 86.8235, 69.4502, 83.4548, 50.7144, 69.2857, 78.8022,
        84.8715, 82.6771, 66.7462, 92.3707, 57.3389, 59.1912, 64.7928, 50.5086,
        70.2607, 59.4710, 66.3204, 85.7392, 59.9484, 67.0398],
       requires_grad=True)
Epoch: 2, Batch: 27/27, Loss: 17.1103
tensor([94.8396, 47.7485, 78.0562, 45.8186, 54.6031, 62.8082, 97.0123, 42.6491,
        49.2939, 63.6138, 63.0521, 81.5171, 90.7891, 80.0071, 95.8921, 56.1590,
        41.4852, 53.8767, 63.2673, 78.6772, 49.4766, 94.2503, 98.4615, 66.9530,
        63.6475, 67.0220, 56.6936, 91.6121], requires_grad=True)
tensor([62.1698, 75.4327, 82.1964, 59.4343, 50.2536, 64.4844, 58.9443, 54.2911,
        84.7635, 86.3406, 70.8897, 67.1416, 62.9637, 84.3366, 73.2613, 61.0178,
        66.0300, 50.4722, 63.6874, 81.0323, 72.0341, 58.7610, 50.0501, 83.4472,
        55.3672, 95.6088, 73.8018, 76.4247], requires_grad=True)
Epoch: 3, Batch: 9/27, Loss: 17.8119
tensor([82.2704, 50.6209, 58.9570, 51.2795, 79.5306, 67.9308, 92.2698, 63.5773,
        56.8274, 61.3201, 44.5039, 65.5686, 87.8466, 76.0954, 61.9486, 95.3668,
        70.9968, 64.0553, 63.2937, 52.2733, 65.8569, 58.2130, 53.6721, 67.3207,
        57.7698, 56.9690, 58.3066, 44.2238, 64.5987, 70.2208],
       requires_grad=True)
tensor([51.0455, 76.3158, 57.3756, 82.5455, 85.4684, 56.4872, 58.5365, 56.0037,
        60.9901, 88.4345, 52.9059, 90.8840, 89.8407, 62.0913, 75.5262, 64.4879,
        72.9262, 53.6481, 79.2563, 95.9649, 69.1330, 70.2464, 69.6060, 93.9474,
        64.3737, 51.2440, 83.0002, 72.6110, 57.1436, 55.5186],
       requires_grad=True)
Epoch: 3, Batch: 18/27, Loss: 17.4416
tensor([40.0613, 70.0793, 60.5794, 59.1018, 45.5982, 54.0367, 62.2104, 73.6662,
        86.5103, 54.8158, 70.0184, 62.6612, 91.0298, 55.2815, 75.6679, 87.5383,
        94.3884, 72.1571, 91.4030, 53.0538, 57.8325, 58.1072, 46.9029, 87.2880,
        56.4656, 51.6655, 95.3320, 86.6001, 41.3867, 40.2379],
       requires_grad=True)
tensor([88.6561, 58.7078, 69.4078, 67.1528, 50.7712, 91.1795, 52.4668, 75.2709,
        76.7339, 50.1979, 50.2144, 84.7016, 96.6278, 71.0694, 60.9386, 55.6673,
        56.6326, 83.8243, 53.8708, 98.8558, 86.6001, 94.5085, 72.0718, 50.1646,
        55.0185, 87.9708, 57.8561, 55.5016, 59.8611, 68.6991],
       requires_grad=True)
Epoch: 3, Batch: 27/27, Loss: 17.4504
tensor([72.7314, 60.7175, 53.9855, 57.4666, 82.4162, 66.7413, 55.2051, 59.9257,
        58.9127, 73.4830, 75.8190, 65.0392, 54.2405, 60.5175, 47.5959, 83.1407,
        59.2927, 84.1498, 84.3692, 42.3428, 82.2967, 58.5331, 51.5464, 60.2221,
        67.5387, 52.4325, 57.5325, 47.3783], requires_grad=True)
tensor([60.5723, 60.1924, 70.8114, 50.4803, 58.1319, 80.1705, 66.4312, 89.0722,
        93.2700, 57.5328, 60.6241, 60.1328, 63.7820, 63.5863, 84.6494, 60.0858,
        59.9835, 71.8713, 57.7989, 86.3545, 69.3061, 86.5655, 53.9679, 75.1453,
        77.0582, 70.7568, 58.1772, 61.9726], requires_grad=True)
Epoch: 4, Batch: 9/27, Loss: 18.1384
tensor([82.3070, 85.3538, 72.8642, 47.8082, 59.7182, 59.2915, 76.4326, 54.2006,
        73.1154, 87.4654, 45.8308, 52.3484, 80.7802, 77.7646, 68.4709, 80.5991,
        91.5891, 66.4647, 49.1979, 56.2557, 56.4740, 94.3136, 56.6697, 53.9137,
        56.9082, 78.9181, 49.6007, 67.7416, 80.6753, 70.3532],
       requires_grad=True)
tensor([60.2717, 86.6999, 64.2365, 88.1633, 53.8815, 81.7314, 61.1522, 92.9598,
        66.8077, 71.1812, 81.9466, 79.8262, 89.1501, 54.1123, 63.3308, 74.7497,
        65.1505, 88.4136, 59.0808, 52.8962, 65.0422, 75.4538, 58.9566, 62.3545,
        70.3164, 52.3869, 86.5237, 74.5544, 62.8599, 80.0702],
       requires_grad=True)
Epoch: 4, Batch: 18/27, Loss: 17.2953
tensor([61.3385, 74.5446, 78.0570, 49.8379, 46.4597, 52.4003, 79.5377, 42.2156,
        57.8949, 71.9619, 56.1718, 79.7147, 53.4191, 81.9996, 68.3521, 86.1803,
        55.5176, 61.2195, 54.5858, 52.7346, 68.9376, 96.3046, 58.1285, 74.5249,
        66.0254, 60.8960, 80.6320, 51.5020, 70.0989, 64.0698],
       requires_grad=True)
tensor([92.4680, 62.2713, 78.5433, 79.3340, 92.7359, 73.3614, 62.7409, 72.2642,
        73.9617, 73.6664, 70.8200, 84.1151, 83.4709, 92.3448, 67.2721, 51.4930,
        76.3888, 83.3918, 50.6546, 77.4105, 71.5623, 58.0631, 72.5162, 76.0948,
        88.3322, 73.2219, 60.4744, 71.6238, 63.6689, 57.9917],
       requires_grad=True)
Epoch: 4, Batch: 27/27, Loss: 18.0093
tensor([59.6312, 57.4130, 64.0593, 61.1920, 93.9593, 89.4862, 61.1555, 49.9394,
        67.2684, 72.0958, 63.6711, 48.5623, 66.9767, 86.2426, 86.2264, 63.0791,
        53.7726, 47.9901, 63.8387, 83.3108, 73.5537, 47.6019, 89.2188, 59.2598,
        88.5598, 67.8026, 73.0152, 85.3148], requires_grad=True)
tensor([74.3132, 80.9916, 68.3390, 58.1556, 54.1983, 58.0227, 65.3027, 59.3029,
        89.6700, 64.9410, 68.0343, 89.9777, 77.0386, 50.6062, 58.7941, 64.7704,
        57.8073, 65.8238, 74.6521, 59.9156, 57.2274, 80.4793, 61.6926, 74.2988,
        55.1182, 75.2684, 52.7505, 55.4685], requires_grad=True)
Epoch: 5, Batch: 9/27, Loss: 17.9806
tensor([57.2678, 81.2281, 74.7805, 46.7722, 58.9347, 78.9594, 60.7869, 83.7890,
        68.3800, 87.0541, 47.9125, 50.2301, 78.9676, 59.2820, 70.3478, 53.3539,
        50.0634, 60.3262, 56.4910, 94.3532, 63.7043, 92.1389, 63.8875, 59.3791,
        43.4143, 69.1011, 67.8122, 44.4809, 84.9866, 54.3083],
       requires_grad=True)
tensor([50.9311, 60.2972, 61.2609, 55.9406, 80.4684, 88.9120, 89.9292, 77.9640,
        56.2489, 59.8310, 57.2860, 59.7226, 79.6746, 60.7360, 53.9811, 74.6140,
        76.4517, 60.6918, 76.7201, 57.1106, 59.0756, 65.2936, 93.3607, 64.5235,
        57.8904, 76.1771, 61.5165, 59.0318, 65.1991, 75.8645],
       requires_grad=True)
Epoch: 5, Batch: 18/27, Loss: 16.8090
tensor([58.9872, 89.5177, 55.8378, 47.0189, 59.7681, 62.6307, 75.5642, 52.9005,
        85.8980, 86.2628, 50.0090, 58.7679, 52.7202, 84.5665, 46.3825, 59.1713,
        88.5708, 57.1978, 63.4291, 61.9673, 73.8314, 66.5727, 48.9828, 64.8347,
        58.6389, 53.5967, 88.2500, 65.1430, 82.0754, 61.5766],
       requires_grad=True)
tensor([57.4783, 89.0712, 51.3146, 55.9848, 54.5457, 52.3762, 80.5094, 52.0920,
        60.1316, 59.0776, 56.5066, 62.4609, 74.8909, 56.2636, 85.8026, 55.5823,
        76.4805, 57.6777, 86.6087, 68.3543, 61.3738, 71.6597, 73.5716, 62.5829,
        73.3047, 67.2005, 51.6375, 86.4499, 57.4254, 88.9810],
       requires_grad=True)
Epoch: 5, Batch: 27/27, Loss: 16.7111
tensor([56.6081, 58.7530, 54.1565, 66.4378, 45.4340, 61.4544, 54.6304, 47.5907,
        77.9514, 44.4934, 48.1107, 80.5940, 52.7570, 54.2707, 56.2680, 67.5394,
        86.3218, 57.1030, 79.9301, 40.7618, 61.5953, 78.9045, 61.0187, 60.0057,
        68.5145, 58.8158, 51.3629, 71.6325], requires_grad=True)
tensor([84.9949, 64.0226, 60.7451, 93.0122, 59.3846, 52.7784, 97.0211, 56.1173,
        54.6407, 56.3277, 51.6263, 62.9494, 59.0675, 65.0713, 80.4183, 88.8788,
        64.3612, 95.9482, 58.1799, 79.8095, 73.4065, 79.9338, 58.1960, 53.0178,
        90.0528, 73.7051, 84.3292, 80.7738], requires_grad=True)
Epoch: 6, Batch: 9/27, Loss: 16.6897
tensor([65.4497, 56.9739, 87.4846, 69.5451, 44.0725, 58.3681, 54.8438, 64.1122,
        86.8856, 84.6581, 65.5492, 73.6265, 82.6922, 67.6248, 47.1774, 53.4978,
        43.7388, 73.1866, 52.9227, 68.0234, 60.0697, 95.9996, 82.3293, 78.8084,
        62.6796, 78.9812, 80.2351, 48.8709, 70.0334, 67.6575],
       requires_grad=True)
tensor([92.1165, 83.0411, 84.2265, 68.8209, 60.3567, 86.1129, 52.0259, 63.7899,
        65.0198, 79.5885, 53.0964, 68.1716, 77.5050, 51.5475, 75.5078, 63.8850,
        86.9938, 71.2247, 73.3777, 55.8522, 80.8890, 75.1488, 55.5086, 87.1030,
        61.9067, 97.1250, 50.5858, 85.1667, 89.4470, 91.1488],
       requires_grad=True)
Epoch: 6, Batch: 18/27, Loss: 17.0629
tensor([51.7950, 60.6460, 65.3508, 51.9049, 55.9367, 57.0474, 65.4438, 54.5296,
        60.8146, 60.8897, 59.3483, 64.9326, 63.6346, 57.8081, 53.3916, 85.6987,
        61.4804, 67.3160, 54.5224, 75.0937, 63.4710, 80.0314, 76.4021, 91.5088,
        88.8462, 80.4177, 77.0866, 42.2610, 57.5132, 77.2586],
       requires_grad=True)
tensor([81.9808, 85.0985, 79.1199, 87.6328, 80.7619, 85.0474, 52.2518, 56.4531,
        69.3352, 71.0087, 63.1048, 51.8550, 64.1063, 51.1225, 92.8195, 55.7550,
        68.2596, 82.7474, 65.4062, 77.7714, 89.4541, 64.0880, 54.7507, 76.9190,
        84.0286, 53.0559, 52.7546, 70.5727, 79.7643, 64.2686],
       requires_grad=True)
Epoch: 6, Batch: 27/27, Loss: 17.6954
tensor([76.5602, 72.1836, 49.3741, 63.4085, 73.7881, 72.4800, 87.1925, 62.6605,
        65.3535, 59.9440, 53.1974, 62.9022, 57.5815, 61.8317, 64.7846, 63.1556,
        58.7673, 51.0617, 60.6637, 54.9090, 70.0491, 64.9448, 50.5592, 54.0959,
        71.8087, 75.3748, 55.4035, 48.6126], requires_grad=True)
tensor([63.2463, 60.5528, 68.3823, 62.7072, 87.9874, 54.6115, 52.5863, 75.2144,
        64.2897, 54.6900, 70.1440, 66.8206, 50.0383, 68.2501, 77.9751, 68.6948,
        53.3203, 73.0439, 76.7905, 79.9796, 80.7547, 76.2516, 80.6727, 84.0519,
        71.6932, 67.7335, 53.3536, 50.0961], requires_grad=True)
Epoch: 7, Batch: 9/27, Loss: 17.4918
tensor([47.0772, 75.8355, 59.3544, 57.7901, 49.7219, 78.1168, 61.6336, 55.9233,
        86.2108, 71.7556, 67.1018, 79.2255, 56.9894, 85.5001, 59.2113, 54.6779,
        47.1590, 53.2321, 67.7539, 57.4024, 61.9119, 63.4207, 93.2538, 54.0693,
        73.9383, 55.2062, 91.2652, 48.6580, 87.6571, 91.1912],
       requires_grad=True)
tensor([55.6032, 67.1066, 81.7661, 97.5470, 71.6377, 72.7943, 80.5347, 89.2188,
        74.2289, 73.4098, 74.6018, 61.7872, 86.9024, 89.4027, 82.2759, 63.4166,
        64.7452, 64.8250, 93.6380, 71.8627, 87.9684, 58.5993, 53.6517, 84.7240,
        60.1890, 57.7291, 54.7577, 91.0874, 65.6803, 57.5784],
       requires_grad=True)
Epoch: 7, Batch: 18/27, Loss: 16.7108
tensor([64.9785, 75.1662, 52.2347, 57.3093, 70.6795, 72.0958, 53.4581, 87.1598,
        74.3221, 65.9217, 73.4595, 54.6452, 57.2360, 87.4990, 43.9649, 75.6831,
        87.7122, 67.0723, 59.5843, 59.2888, 42.5833, 62.9549, 56.9336, 75.3479,
        70.1061, 95.3960, 55.1178, 86.8702, 47.7267, 67.6467],
       requires_grad=True)
tensor([73.7790, 97.4820, 75.9761, 52.2530, 70.9638, 64.9410, 64.8678, 67.9897,
        54.8797, 72.8583, 61.6201, 86.7597, 80.5616, 63.7166, 71.6646, 58.4443,
        65.3807, 89.1221, 75.3413, 81.5615, 51.9781, 76.4281, 58.4931, 89.5656,
        56.8869, 64.9279, 62.2209, 54.9291, 87.6356, 94.6970],
       requires_grad=True)
Epoch: 7, Batch: 27/27, Loss: 18.1450
tensor([89.2341, 60.6242, 86.7899, 94.8531, 70.8553, 79.9033, 52.9623, 66.0363,
        49.2871, 60.8167, 53.1052, 58.8080, 87.4095, 72.7156, 59.7367, 52.9604,
        58.2651, 65.7046, 60.0887, 81.8496, 91.0982, 85.3468, 48.8302, 47.8754,
        59.0912, 51.3230, 53.6966, 89.9425], requires_grad=True)
tensor([76.3499, 88.5086, 55.0087, 54.3850, 55.1252, 90.4761, 95.0625, 89.9320,
        73.1018, 52.1641, 62.3784, 53.2634, 51.6547, 79.0873, 58.4434, 58.9358,
        65.0304, 58.0769, 80.0069, 82.9520, 55.0427, 63.5757, 78.1684, 84.1857,
        56.2341, 70.1631, 73.3770, 53.9472], requires_grad=True)
Epoch: 8, Batch: 9/27, Loss: 17.4907
tensor([70.4592, 46.6856, 63.4466, 79.5083, 57.7531, 72.9300, 53.7672, 49.7645,
        46.5434, 55.7625, 64.3704, 75.5201, 60.8868, 71.5225, 82.0176, 70.9549,
        79.6291, 91.2377, 71.9711, 93.9967, 66.4274, 71.2158, 71.5053, 68.2202,
        62.6273, 45.1615, 55.2313, 56.9580, 87.5294, 75.7781],
       requires_grad=True)
tensor([62.3556, 88.8004, 71.8320, 82.7305, 65.3166, 53.8224, 85.8465, 62.9721,
        73.3567, 83.3668, 67.4274, 87.7643, 84.0388, 55.1628, 77.1584, 54.4613,
        60.3723, 59.3901, 60.5592, 68.5396, 69.1184, 56.9077, 66.9523, 76.1375,
        51.6081, 65.4840, 96.8460, 78.9510, 75.7698, 85.3225],
       requires_grad=True)
Epoch: 8, Batch: 18/27, Loss: 16.9433
tensor([81.4433, 58.6241, 59.8896, 91.8082, 57.7728, 57.5354, 76.3100, 58.4701,
        57.3614, 53.7688, 65.2457, 64.8684, 68.8134, 56.4877, 74.3897, 66.8302,
        60.6947, 82.5878, 65.7431, 62.3632, 90.7158, 65.0815, 49.5395, 73.7490,
        63.3452, 52.1292, 79.8929, 84.9169, 43.1312, 39.7226],
       requires_grad=True)
tensor([57.7647, 50.5289, 57.1132, 62.8068, 52.2719, 75.4570, 64.0335, 84.0655,
        67.2097, 74.4249, 84.1444, 60.9113, 81.3251, 60.2410, 76.7956, 73.2597,
        94.8752, 54.9523, 65.6400, 53.0588, 53.5558, 57.7012, 51.5153, 80.6335,
        70.7561, 65.3511, 58.8262, 85.3769, 70.4071, 70.4009],
       requires_grad=True)
Epoch: 8, Batch: 27/27, Loss: 16.5463
tensor([44.9507, 59.5018, 51.7240, 64.0446, 77.4158, 48.5121, 75.8036, 86.0016,
        49.6492, 55.1716, 43.0580, 75.4771, 89.3402, 58.5754, 66.7130, 73.8062,
        82.2343, 74.0247, 79.2761, 78.4597, 82.9454, 48.8336, 79.6960, 62.3197,
        83.8502, 63.6007, 57.2919, 52.1446], requires_grad=True)
tensor([62.1890, 85.2769, 81.4473, 50.7784, 62.2193, 68.8312, 53.9236, 67.1576,
        63.6198, 87.8260, 63.4054, 73.5527, 63.9165, 66.5124, 86.1478, 68.9236,
        66.1425, 68.4562, 58.5301, 67.1681, 74.9645, 52.1364, 60.4453, 52.3903,
        54.3567, 65.7043, 53.8991, 68.6928], requires_grad=True)
Epoch: 9, Batch: 9/27, Loss: 16.2674
tensor([59.7783, 84.8130, 45.3971, 48.2831, 65.3260, 71.2625, 71.5556, 88.1735,
        51.3328, 73.2849, 61.8224, 48.0877, 63.4327, 94.0175, 73.2625, 91.7749,
        64.9406, 80.2605, 52.1976, 74.8846, 56.2506, 62.1967, 77.6601, 61.0732,
        53.5962, 68.7588, 74.5650, 49.2382, 95.1397, 85.7921],
       requires_grad=True)
tensor([51.9130, 73.4181, 77.6557, 82.8297, 86.1708, 75.5273, 80.5328, 78.2242,
        58.2166, 58.9178, 81.3410, 81.0710, 78.3509, 83.9392, 74.1925, 56.3876,
        78.6955, 87.7481, 82.5476, 96.3245, 52.6445, 66.2667, 64.0054, 73.9307,
        84.5926, 92.5884, 96.1174, 80.4493, 53.6515, 65.0110],
       requires_grad=True)
Epoch: 9, Batch: 18/27, Loss: 17.0952
tensor([37.6595, 84.1128, 57.6884, 46.9237, 56.3446, 59.1772, 84.4413, 50.8406,
        54.4072, 68.8383, 75.5205, 51.8940, 69.6777, 90.4713, 52.2767, 55.3106,
        89.4968, 57.2022, 68.9578, 84.3045, 62.0941, 89.8617, 52.5343, 95.6473,
        62.3262, 53.8856, 50.2572, 52.4697, 93.3242, 59.8864],
       requires_grad=True)
tensor([79.5688, 92.8399, 87.2983, 50.4998, 52.4821, 69.4870, 86.4203, 70.1498,
        65.2413, 65.8360, 56.3609, 83.7946, 53.6900, 71.6870, 50.2632, 65.5489,
        68.0694, 76.0816, 67.1003, 87.0674, 83.9564, 52.5306, 67.1315, 67.2713,
        68.0139, 71.1475, 50.0188, 86.5994, 50.3018, 79.0913],
       requires_grad=True)
Epoch: 9, Batch: 27/27, Loss: 16.1039
tensor([50.1723, 55.9694, 58.1345, 58.5947, 49.3185, 73.3103, 54.6258, 65.1321,
        73.5088, 48.8491, 68.2980, 67.7505, 81.3056, 50.1265, 94.2160, 66.1108,
        59.4193, 70.6258, 84.0702, 68.8523, 59.1006, 68.4027, 86.2330, 69.8247,
        57.4993, 63.6571, 55.7037, 46.0402], requires_grad=True)
tensor([68.7268, 57.1353, 68.9692, 97.2102, 60.3846, 83.0645, 51.6379, 58.1405,
        54.3410, 74.6399, 85.0214, 88.2853, 52.7111, 52.7800, 65.1275, 50.7308,
        70.6876, 69.8980, 91.4059, 71.4718, 64.7826, 63.7519, 60.8230, 59.7393,
        51.5532, 56.5856, 61.4629, 80.2751], requires_grad=True)
Epoch: 10, Batch: 9/27, Loss: 17.4092
tensor([60.9789, 89.5557, 82.2997, 84.5127, 54.5755, 51.5405, 73.9943, 65.5087,
        77.5922, 53.4945, 60.0833, 48.2683, 43.2169, 74.9529, 61.5223, 86.2931,
        74.4847, 56.8721, 95.1353, 77.5217, 88.8361, 79.3741, 53.5121, 58.1608,
        67.9512, 54.9445, 67.8808, 51.0581, 76.5043, 86.3261],
       requires_grad=True)
tensor([95.2814, 56.8884, 51.2599, 79.4898, 83.1415, 63.8247, 59.9266, 66.3693,
        56.8304, 58.8284, 92.8936, 66.3768, 65.5626, 55.7012, 81.1105, 85.1539,
        56.2308, 93.6544, 58.6941, 77.8071, 55.2056, 53.5345, 98.3519, 74.8302,
        72.7801, 71.5537, 62.0966, 74.3412, 81.1796, 87.9606],
       requires_grad=True)
Epoch: 10, Batch: 18/27, Loss: 17.6877
tensor([52.5867, 55.4056, 90.6123, 48.6503, 63.8506, 66.3056, 53.0244, 51.7491,
        46.0211, 65.4287, 79.1347, 52.4135, 58.5100, 60.6681, 48.2982, 53.7817,
        49.3548, 52.5132, 52.1970, 59.0500, 51.1250, 59.6318, 44.3950, 62.3171,
        88.8943, 59.0210, 48.0230, 67.1373, 53.6011, 74.6469],
       requires_grad=True)
tensor([65.2274, 53.8242, 52.8306, 98.8989, 70.6807, 69.1512, 75.0717, 79.2763,
        76.1288, 65.9906, 94.4736, 75.9710, 77.4560, 55.4111, 82.8062, 64.9445,
        60.9662, 57.5809, 87.6801, 60.6461, 77.1414, 54.7315, 80.4020, 53.4269,
        91.5566, 66.4816, 78.5918, 53.2440, 97.9356, 72.5576],
       requires_grad=True)
Epoch: 10, Batch: 27/27, Loss: 16.4993
tensor([60.7051, 87.7766, 69.9851, 77.9496, 56.6728, 76.3336, 86.5649, 73.1507,
        55.3927, 83.8575, 65.5520, 65.7547, 58.7896, 56.4687, 75.3076, 80.5790,
        64.9253, 80.9019, 51.1328, 70.8095, 81.2056, 74.7989, 70.7653, 79.8609,
        64.1591, 56.7267, 60.4743, 73.4796], requires_grad=True)
tensor([57.3263, 64.1434, 75.9717, 50.1461, 68.7356, 66.1837, 76.3986, 76.9856,
        51.2058, 57.9763, 86.0767, 60.7704, 61.8576, 50.3020, 50.7623, 74.0178,
        55.9524, 91.5254, 74.4259, 95.0930, 78.9308, 62.0408, 83.2008, 50.9269,
        55.5148, 51.0136, 54.7389, 81.0178], requires_grad=True)
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. We don't provide debugging services. The following references give advice on debugging your code. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), [Six Debugging Techniques for Python Programmers](https://medium.com/techtofreedom/six-debugging-techniques-for-python-programmers-cb25a4baaf4b)  or [Ultimate Guide to Python Debugging](https://towardsdatascience.com/ultimate-guide-to-python-debugging-854dea731e1b)